# Selenium Webdriver get percentage of File Download and response Object

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have recently started working with selenium.

Currently, I am using Webdriver to download and upload files.

While uploading, browser submits a form and next action happens only when page is navigated.

But for download, browser keeps downloading the file and proceeds with further actions.

Here, the percentage of file downloaded is required so that I can wait until download is completed.
Also, is there a way to get HTTP Response object through Selenium to check response headers.

I am using `ChromeOptions` and `DesiredCapabilities` to set different properties.

`webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDesiredCapabilities);`

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromePreferences = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePreferences.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePreferences.put("download.default_directory", browserDownloadDirectoryPath);
chromePreferences.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "true");
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePreferences);
chromeOptions.addArguments("--test-type");
chromeDesiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
chromeDesiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
```

Comment: You can't get the download percentage with WebDriver because that would require being able to observe the http traffic, which selenium intentionally does not allow you to do.  An alternative could be to use WebDriver to get the URL of the resource you would like to download, and then offload that task to another library that works alongside WebDriver

Comment: Or another idea you could try is to go look at the size of the file being downloaded.  And wait for it to finish growing.  If your only goal is to wait for it to finish.  (This solution could be more finicky though with slow connections, make sure your sleep times are long enough inbetween each check)

Comment: @Julian and Venkatesh - I know I am coming back after 3 years but we can get the download percentage using the chrome download status. Check my below answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 3 years old post but wanted to provide the answer so that it might help someone.

You can defiantly get the current status of your file download (I mean the percentage of download) using the chrome downloads status.

Below is the python implement that will return the percentage of latest file download.

```
def getDownLoadedPercentage():
    endTime = time.time() + 180
    while True:
        try:
            downloadPercentage = driver.execute_script(
                "return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('#progress').value")
            if downloadPercentage:
                return downloadPercentage
        except:
            pass
        time.sleep(1)
        if time.time() > endTime:
            break
```

Just call the method when you need to know the status of your download as shown below.

```
print(getDownLoadedPercentage())
```